# Crystal Reports formula type mismatch

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, type-mismatch

I'm loading a Crystal Report from a `VB6` application (Crystal Reports 6) and I need to pass in the vales for two formulas.

To do this, I've got

```
crExport.Formulas("@thisYear") = Mid(DB_Period_Name$, Len(DB_Period_Name$) - 5, 2)
crExport.Formulas("@thisPeriod") = Mid(DB_Period_Name$, Len(DB_Period_Name$) - 7, 2)
```

However, when I run the application and try to view the report, I get a runtime error

> Type mismatch

once I get to the first formula line. What is causing this issue?

I've tried removing the @ signs from the formula name, I've converted both value to integers before assigning them but these both produced the same error.

Comment: I don't have access to my code at the moment to get the exact syntax, but you need to loop through ALL formulas (numeric index) and check the name (or something similar) property of each one.  If you haven't figured this out on your own by this evening, or someone else hasn't shown you the correct method, I'll try to post an example answer.

Comment: @BillHileman for now I have a temporary solution, but I've hard-coded the index of the formulas. If you could post your method when you're able to then that would be perfect, as mine will obviously break if other formulas get added to the report at a later date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to this was by using the index of the formulas, rather than the names, to set the values.

So in this case

```
crxReport.FormulaFields(0).Text = Mid(DB_Period_Name$, Len(DB_Period_Name$) - 5, 2)
crxReport.FormulaFields(1).Text = Mid(DB_Period_Name$, Len(DB_Period_Name$) - 7, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I set formula values for my Ageing Report:

```
' Global Declarations
Public crxApp As CRAXDRT.Application

Public crxRpt As CRAXDRT.Report
Public crxTable As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable
Public crxFormula As CRAXDRT.FormulaFieldDefinition
```

Section of the ageing report:

```
  For Each crxFormula In crxRpt.FormulaFields
    Select Case crxFormula.FormulaFieldName
      Case CR_FORMULA_COMPANY_NAME
        crxFormula.Text = QuoteIt(Trim(strCompanyName(1)))
      Case CR_FORMULA_GROUP_1_HIGHLIGHT
        crxFormula.Text = Replace$(strHCGroup(1), " ", "")
      Case CR_FORMULA_GROUP_2_HIGHLIGHT
        crxFormula.Text = Replace$(strHCGroup(2), " ", "")
      Case CR_FORMULA_GROUP_3_HIGHLIGHT
        crxFormula.Text = Replace$(strHCGroup(3), " ", "")
      Case CR_FORMULA_GROUP_4_HIGHLIGHT
        crxFormula.Text = Replace$(strHCGroup(4), " ", "")
      Case CR_FORMULA_GRAND_HIGHLIGHT
        crxFormula.Text = Replace$(strHCGrand, " ", "")
      Case "Processing Date"
        crxFormula.Text = "Date(" & QuoteIt(Format(dtpProcDate.Value, "Short Date")) & ")"
      Case "Days Col 1"
        crxFormula.Text = CStr(txtPeriod(0).Value)
      Case "Days Col 2"
        crxFormula.Text = CStr(txtPeriod(1).Value)
      Case "Days Col 3"
        crxFormula.Text = CStr(txtPeriod(2).Value)
      Case "Days Col 4"
        crxFormula.Text = CStr(txtPeriod(3).Value)
      Case "Age Type"
        Select Case True
          Case optAgingType(0).Value
            crxFormula.Text = QuoteIt(optAgingType(0).Tag)
          Case optAgingType(1).Value
            crxFormula.Text = QuoteIt(optAgingType(1).Tag)
          Case optAgingType(2).Value
            crxFormula.Text = QuoteIt(optAgingType(2).Tag)
          Case optAgingType(3).Value
            crxFormula.Text = QuoteIt(optAgingType(3).Tag)
        End Select
      Case "Summary"
        crxFormula.Text = IIf(optReportType(1).Value, "True", "False")
    End Select
    crxFormula.Check blnFormulaOK, strFormulaErr
    If Not blnFormulaOK Then
      MsgBox CR_FORMULA_ERROR_TEXT & crxFormula.FormulaFieldName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
             strFormulaErr & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
             Trim(crxFormula.Text), vbCritical, CR_FORMULA_ERROR_TITLE
      Exit For
    End If
  Next crxFormula
```

Comment: What are you declaring/defining `crxFormula` as? When I try to compile this as is, it says "Variable not defined"

Comment: I added the declaration to my answer.  I'm not certain which reference needs to be included in the project.

Comment: With the way my reports are created and are done so throughout the application, this was unfortunately won't work for me. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: For what it's worth, I create my Crystal Reports using the report writer itself (I use an older version 8.5 because my data files are older Btrieve data) but I access the .rpt files directly within the code using the API's and show them through the report viewer.  this allows me to customize them on-the-fly.  What version are you using and how are you getting the crExport variable in your code?

Comment: I'm just using a `CrystalReport` control, dragging it onto the form